# config file for upstart with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart

Can you advise a upstart config file for nodejs on ubuntu? I've found the follows tutorial: http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit but it seem very old.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little shell script that creates my config files.

```
create_upstart() {
  project=$1
  file=$2
  conf="/etc/init/${project}_${file}.conf"

  cat > $conf << EOF
  #!upstart

  description "Node Process - $1"
  author      "Geert Pasteels"

  respawn

  start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
  stop  on shutdown

  script
    export NODE_ENV="production"
    export PORT="3001"
    exec /usr/bin/node /var/www/$project/current/$file.js >> /var/www/$project/shared/logs/$file 2>&1
  end script
EOF

  echo $conf

  # Restart upstart script
  stop ${project}_${file}
  start ${project}_${file}
  echo Restarted ${project}_${file}
}

create_upstart "$1" "$2"
```

I use this in combination with [TJ's deploy](https://github.com/visionmedia/deploy). So in my post deploy hook i do `startup app file.`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using nvm on my server. How can I run nodejs with this one? And should I create an specific user for nodejs